# Why it shows an error in the store() conferece?

Tags: laravel

I have this code to store a conference. There is a form field that is for the user to select the available payment methods. The form field is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">
       Select the payment methods</label>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="payment_mb" id="payment_mb">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            MB
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="payment_c" id="payment_c">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Credit Card
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code to store is like below.

But it shows an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 
'on' for column 'payment_mb' at row 1 (SQL: 
 insert into `conferences` (`name`, `organizer_id`, 
 `organizer_name`, `organizer_email`, `invoice_entity`, 
 `payment_mb`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
 values (a, 2, John W, emailtest@test.com, 1,
 on, 2018-07-25 19:17:26, 2018-07-25 19:17:26))
```

Do you know why?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $conference = Conference::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'organizer_id' => Auth::id(),
            'organizer_name' => $request->organizer_name,
            'organizer_email' => $request->organizer_email,
            'payment_mb' =>$request->payment_mb ? : 0,
            'payment_c'  => $request->payment_c ? : 0
        ]);

        $conference->categories()->attach($request->categories);

        $conference->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'conference created.');
    }
```

The $request->all() shows like:

```
array:25 [▼
  "_token" => ""
  "name" => "test"
  "organizer_name" => "John W"
  "organizer_email" => "..."
  "payment_mb" => "on"
  "payment_c" => "on"
  "invoice_issuer" => "1"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `on` wouldn't be an `int` value. Your request has the value `'on'` for that field.

```
'payment_mb' =>$request->payment_mb ? : 0,
```

You could maybe try:

```
'payment_mb' => (int) boolval($request->payment_mb),
```

Or even just:

```
'payment_mb' => (bool) $request->payment_mb,
```

[PHP Docs - boolval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php)

You could also actually set a value for the checkbox to be a `'1'` or something like that.

Some validation might be good.

**Update**

I think i was looking for `filter_var`:

```
filter_var($thatInput, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);

// 'on' => true
// null => false
// 'off' => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct store code?
payment_c does not appear in the sql statement even though it was set in your code.